# Discerning between polymorphic types in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, typeinfo

Here is some code:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>

class Super {};

class Sub1 : public Super {};

class Sub2 : public Super {};

int main() {
    std::vector<Super*> vec;

    vec.push_back(new Sub1);
    vec.push_back(new Sub2);

    assert(typeid(vec[0]) == typeid(vec[1]));
    assert(typeid(vec[0]) != typeid(vec[1]));
}
```

Unfortunately the first assert passes, and the second does not. I am not surprised by that result, but it would have been nice to be able to discern types that way.

My (sort of hackish) workaround:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>

enum SubTypeEnum {
    Sub1_T,
    Sub2_T
};

class Super {
    SubTypeEnum _type;
public:
    Super(SubTypeEnum __type) : _type(__type) {}
    SubTypeEnum type() { return _type; }
};

class Sub1 : public Super {
public:
    Sub1() : Super(Sub1_T) {}
};

class Sub2 : public Super {
public:
    Sub2() : Super(Sub2_T) {}
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Super*> vec;

    vec.push_back(new Sub1);
    vec.push_back(new Sub2);

    assert(vec[0]->type() != vec[1]->type());
    assert(vec[0]->type() == vec[1]->type());
}
```

This produces the desired result, but seems messy. Is there a better way to find out which type I am dealing with?

Comment: I assume you're missing a `*` on both arguments of the second assert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you're using `typeinfo` slightly wrongly, when applied to a pointer it returns the type of the pointer, but when applied to a dereferenced pointer it returns the actual type of the object pointed to, so long as the base type has at least one virtual function ( usually it would be the destructor). So the following will work:

```
class Super {
  public:
  virtual ~Super() {}
};

class Sub1 : public Super {};

class Sub2 : public Super {};

int main() {
    std::vector<Super*> vec;

    vec.push_back(new Sub1);
    vec.push_back(new Sub2);

    assert(typeid(vec[0])  == typeid(vec[1]));
    assert(typeid(*vec[0]) != typeid(*vec[1]));
}
```

Secondly, doing this kind of type switching is generally considered a sign that you're doing something wrong. For example instead of

```
void foo(Base* v) {
  //Here SOMETHING and SOMETHING_ELSE are constants we calculate elsewhere.
  if( typeid(*v)==SOMETHING ) { cout<<"Got a SOMETHING"<<endl; }
  else if (typeid(*v)==SOMETHING_ELSE ) { cout<<"Got a SOMETHING ELSE"<<endl; }
}
```

or its roughly equivalent

```
void foo(Base* v) {
  if( dynamic_cast<Something*>(v) ) { cout<<"Got a SOMETHING"<<:endl; }
  else if ( dynamic_cast<SomethingElse*>(v) { cout<<"Got a SOMETHING ESLE"<<endl; }
```

it is usual to add the functionality into the base class:

```
class Base
{
  public:
    virtual void printMessage()=0;
};

class Something : public Base
{
   void printMessage() { cout<<"Got a SOMETHING"<<endl; }
}

class SomethingElse : public Base
{
   void printMessage() { cout<<"Got a SOMETHING ELSE"<<endl; }
}

void foo(Base * v)
{
  v->printMessage();
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I tried dereferencing as well, but without any virtual methods and it didn't work. Why does the virtual method make a difference?

Comment: The "silly" answer is because the standard specifies it to be that way. Realistically the reason is that dynamic `typeinfo` is stored in the vtable if it exists. If the vtable doesn't exist then there is no logical place for the type info to go inside the class instance ... Only way to make the vtable exist is to add a virtual function.

Comment: Okay, I don't understand what you're trying to tell me. What signs do you see that I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I am implementing an expression evaluator, and I need a container type which can hold both operators and operands. Since operators and operands don't have much in common, I need to be able to know which is which.

Comment: So basically I have a `std::vector<Token*>` where `Operator` and `Operand` are both derived from `Token`. Since I need to treat `Operator`s differently from `Operand`s, I need to know which is which when I pull them out.

Comment: I mean you'd pull the differences in behaviour into `Operator::doSomething()` and `Operand::doSomething()` functions with a pure virtual `Token::doSomething()`. Then you'd never switch except when creating the initial objects, just loop over the vector and call `v[i]->doSomething()`. In my opinion (and that of many others) this approach tends to lead to more maintainable code and less bugs.

Comment: But I can't do that, because they're used for completely different things. In other words, `BinaryOperator::call()` needs to be passed two `Operand`s, `UnaryOperator::call()` needs to be passed one `Operand`, and `Operand` does not have a `call()` method at all. I need to invoke certain behavior when I pull an `Operator` out of my expression, which is different from the behavior I need when I pull out an `Operand`, or even a different type of `Operator`.